# QUERY works in phpyMyAdmin but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My Query don't work in PHP but when I test it in my database it works well.

Code:

```html
<?php
    //Database connectie
    $link = mysqli_connect("*", "*", "*", "*") or die("Error ". mysqli_error($link));

    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); // or you could use 1G

    //Query //
    $query = "SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1;";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM datakram, datakram2, datakram3, datakram4 WHERE datakram.ISIN = datakram2.ISIN AND datakram2.ISIN = datakram3.ISIN AND datakram3.ISIN = datakram4.ISIN";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

?>
            <table>
                <thead>         
                    <tr class="warning">
                        <th>Naam</th>
                        <th>ISIN</th>
                        <th>Jaar</th>
                        <th>Closely Held Shares</th>
                        <th>Outstanding Sahres</th>
                        <th>Market capitalistion</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['company-name'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['ISIN'];?></td>
                        <td>2017</td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['2017'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['2017-shares'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['2017-market'];?></td>
                    </tr>
<?php 
    }
?>
```

Knows somebody why? I have tried: **$result = mysqli_multi_query($link, $query);** But that didn't work.

I have fix it, don't tell me how ;) but it works. Here if somebody need it:

```html
 //Database connectie
 $link = mysqli_connect("*", "*", "*", "*") or die("Error ". mysqli_error($link));
 
 ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); // or you could use 1G
 
 //Query //
 $query = "SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1;";
 $query .= "SELECT * FROM datakram, datakram2, datakram3, datakram4 WHERE datakram.ISIN = datakram2.ISIN AND datakram2.ISIN = datakram3.ISIN AND datakram3.ISIN = datakram4.ISIN";

 if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {
  do {
 
?>
   <table>
    <thead>   
     <tr class="warning">
      <th>Naam</th>
      <th>ISIN</th>
      <th>Jaar</th>
      <th>Closely Held Shares</th>
      <th>Outstanding Sahres</th>
      <th>Market capitalistion</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php
 if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
?>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['company-name'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['ISIN'];?></td>
      <td>2017</td>
      <td><?php echo $row['2017'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['2017-shares'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['2017-market'];?></td>
     </tr>
<?php 
  }
  }   
  } while (mysqli_next_result($link));
  }
?>
```

Comment: Can you include the PHP code as well.  This helps in checking syntax etc.

Comment: If the Set is part of a single PHP query call, it won't work. Use the multi_query function.

Comment: @NigelRen I have include the PHP code

Comment: It's not a multi query as the second query string is overwriting the first.

Comment: IMHO it would be better to specify the columns your after in the SELECT, so rather than `*` use `datakrim.isin, ` and list just the fields which you are using.

Comment: Also, use the current JOIN syntax instead of FROM comma-separated-tables syntax.

Comment: We stopped writing queries this way in 1992. JOIN us.

Comment: Also any time you find yourself with enumerated column or table names, you can sure that your design is fatally flawed

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, but it works now... :)

Comment: I guess that depends on how you define 'works'